# The application requires that assembly Microsoft.HTMLTrans.Interface version be installed first in the global assembly cache

Tags: wpf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I have created a WPF application. I  have used the microsoft.sharepoint dll to get some data from lists.
I created a deployment package . When i run the setup i get the following error

> unable to install or run the application. The application requires
>   that assembly Microsoft.HTMLTrans.Interface version 12.0.0.0 be installed first
>   in the global assembly cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented the SharePoint  method calls and instead accessed sharepoint lists using the Sharepoint web service approach. 
It resolved the issue.